# Can you force IE8 to recognize background-size: 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I need background image sprites to resize according to the width of their container, without showing the whole sprite, and background-size:100% accomplishes this, like so:

```
#featured ul.icon-controls li.prevention {
   background:url(img/ico1.png) no-repeat;
   background-size:100%;
   height:60px;
   width:50px; 
   background-position: 0 -113px;
}
```

But, alas, I have to support IE8, which does not support background-size. I've found scripts like backgroundSize.js, which force IE8 to render background-size:cover and background-size:contain, but those don't work for sprites. And I need to use a sprite for the various states of each icon (hover/active/inactive).

Is there anything I can do -- hacky solutions are ok given my desperation!

**Here is a fiddle of my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/Pw7fL/**

Comment: Is there a way to mimic the sliding door technique with images as opposed to background images? I was thinking I could put the sprite into a sized div, with overflow:hidden. So you only see one of the icons in the sprite. But I don't know how to accomplish the rollover function with css, if not a background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this!

https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

As I found out it is easy to use!

Comment: I think that only works with contain and cover, right? That's all they mention on their site. This is the successor to backgroundSize.js that I was referring to above, which didn't work for me. But I will give it a shot -- maybe this new one will work! Thank you.

Comment: Oh wow, just tried this solution, and it DID work, using background-size:cover. I'm not sure why I thought I couldn't use :cover... at some point when I tested it, it showed the whole sprite, but I must have had something else wrong. It's a little glitchy, but I will continue to fiddle with it. THANK YOU.